# Visual Studio Debugger Will Not Work

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug an application i made a while ago. When i click the start button, nothing happens but the classic windows error sound and then it stops debugging.

- I then tried to debug a brand new project, same result.
- This is a fresh install of windows and visual studio.
- Hitting Ctrl + F5 works so i am pretty sure it is a problem with the
  debugger.
- I am running visual studio in Administrator Mode

I have tried this in VS2012 and VS2013, both have the same result. But on VS2013 there was an error which may or may not be related.

```
...has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) Access Violation
```

Please let me know of anything i can try to give you more information.

**Update:**
If i debug for x64, it works. But it does not work for x86 or "any cpu"

Comment: Is it updated properly?

Comment: Yes it is fully updated.

Comment: and is windows also updated?

Comment: Yes everything is updated.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Go to Tools-options-Debugging- Just-in-Time and check all check boxes are checked.

Comment: Everything is indeed ticked.

Comment: Have you tried a full clean and rebuild?

Comment: A full clean and rebuild of what?

Comment: It means your visual studio has not istalled correctly.Try to repair it.

Comment: This is a fresh install of visual studio, but i will try the repair.

Comment: Repairing did not fix the issue.

Comment: If i debug for x64, it works. But it does not work for x86 or "any cpu"

Comment: If the install is really fresh its a visual studio bug, but I find that hard to believe. If this is indeed the case you'll need to debug the debugger, and nobody here is going to know the specific problem.

Comment: 1. Anything unusual in your build logs
Enable verbose build logging. Check the output (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx) 2. Try debugging with windbg. Does that also bailout?

Comment: It's more likely that one of the x86 libs his project is dependent on is not binary compatible. You'd need to provide more information about your setup. Have you installed an SDK etc? Have you verified that all the project include/lib/exe paths are correct and consistent?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you first try to clean and rebuild your project, if it doesn't help, it may be a problem with your Visual Studio installation.

You need to repair your Visual Studio. You can do so in **Control Panel** -> **Programs and Features**, look for your version of Visual Studio and click on **Change**. Follow the on-screen instruction to **Repair** your Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding my project will do nothing. This problems occurs on all projects (even new ones with no added code).